# Reading one file and writing to two different files doesn't works when commit-interval is more than 1

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-integration, spring-batch

I am reading one file and based on some business logic writing to two different files. I am using **ClassifierCompositeItemWriter** to write to two different files.

It works only when the commit-interval is 1 or else some records get written to different output file.

Below is the code snippet,

```
<batch:job id="interestJob">
    <batch:step id="verifyFile" parent="VerifyFile">
        <batch:fail on="FAILED"/>
        <batch:next on="*" to="processInterest"/>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="processInterest">
        <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk  reader="itemReader" processor="itemProcessor" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="50" skip-limit="1000000">
        <batch:streams>
                <batch:stream ref="masterCarditemWriter"/>
                 <batch:stream ref="visaitemWriter"/>
            </batch:streams>            

        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter">
        <property name="classifier" ref="classifier" />
</bean>

<bean id="classifier"  class="org.springframework.batch.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier">
    <property name="routerDelegate">
        <bean class="com.scotiabank.sco.report.batch.dda.interest.MyClassifier" />
    </property>
    <property name="matcherMap">
        <map>
        <entry key="visa"   value-ref="visaitemWriter" />
        <entry key="master" value-ref="masterCarditemWriter" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>


public class MyClassifier {
@Classifier
public String classify(Interest dda) {
    return dda.getCardType();

}
```

}

Comment: I have tried it by myself. I don't see the issue you are facing (commit-interval is 10 for me). Please refer to an example I just wrote https://bigzidane.wordpress.com/2016/09/16/spring-batch-multiple-writers/

Comment: We'll need more information because this is known to work.  Have you tried debugging your `Classifier` to see if it's being called for each item?